# Change property of a checkbox without affecting other checkboxes

Tags: jquery, class, for-loop, input

I'm trying to create a form which adds up to a value for daily and length of days but when i try to recreate the product of a php while statement that fetches all rows and then displays info for each row, the forms do not work individually. I'm trying to get it working for as man rows as can be added, while trying to keep code to minimum.

The Fiddle is was working on is here https://jsfiddle.net/shiataz12/oj51vfpm/111/.

Assume the form is part of a php while loop where each form is a new row in a database. #nosday is a $_POST element. All input's are submitted to another page.

So far I've tried to use eq(i) in an attempt as isolating the element by class or name as well as $('#formaddi' + i).children as a prefix to my functions. I've tried changing a few of the checkboxes to radio buttons where i needed only one selected to reduce some of the code needed to do this, however I still need to disable onetent and twotent options when standard is selected, but it disables all of them.

Each form should work individually, I've tried to also use selectors such as ^ to isolate the id or class but it either doesnt work or all of them work together. Any suggestions o idea's. Ideally, an api page for the best function to use in selecting a specific input in one form at a time.

```
<input type="text" value="5" id="nosday"><br><br>
<input type="hidden" value="3" id="countrows"><br>
////////////////////////FIRST FORM/////////////////////////////
<br>
<form id="formaddi1" class="formadd1">

<label for="standardi1">Standard</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="packn1" id ="standardi1" class="pack1 standard1 qr1" value="1050" checked><br><br>

<label for="equippedi1">Equipped</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="packn1" id ="equippedi1" class="pack1 equipped1 qr1" value="0" ><br><br>

<label for="gpsi1">GPS</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="gpsn1" id ="gpsi1" value="20" class ="gps1 qr1"><br><br>

<label for="boosteri1">booster</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="boostern1" id ="boosteri1" value="20" class =" booster1 qr1"><br><br>

<label for="onetenti1">One tent</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="tentn1" id ="onetenti1" class="stent1 onetent1 qr1" value="1350" disabled><br><br>

<label for="twotenti1">Two tents :</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="tentn1" id ="twotenti1" class="stent1 twotent1 qr1" value="1450" disabled><br><br>
Daily :<span id="dailytotali1"> </span><br><br>
Total :<span id="lengthtotali1"> </span>
<br><br>
<br><input tyep="text" id="dailytoti1" name="pricefn11" value="">
<br><input tyep="text" id="lengthtoti1" name="pricefn21" value="">
<br><br><br>
</form>
////////////////////////SECOND FORM/////////////////////////////
<BR>
<form id="formaddi2" class="formadd2">
<label for="standardi2">Standard</label>
<input type="radio" name="packn2" id ="standardi2" class="quip2 standard2 qr2" value="125" checked><br><br>

<label for="equippedi2">Equipped</label>
<input type="radio" name="packn2" id ="equippedi2" class="quip2 equipped2 qr2" value="0" ><br><br>

<label for="gpsi2">GPS</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="gpsn2" id ="gpsi2" value="20" class ="gps2 qr2"><br><br>

<label for="boosteri2">booster</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="boostern2" id ="boosteri2" value="20" class ="booster2 qr2"><br><br>

<label for="onetenti2">One tent</label>
<input type="radio" name="tentn2" id ="onetenti2" class="stent2 onetent2 qr2" value="1350" disabled><br><br>

<label for="twotenti2">Two tents :</label>
<input type="radio" name="tentn2" id ="twotenti2" class="stent2 twotent2 qr2" value="1450" disabled><br><br>
Daily :<span id="dailytotali2"> </span><br><br>
Total :<span id="lengthtotali2"> </span><br><br>

<br><input tyep="text" id="dailytoti2" name="pricefn12" value="">
<br><input tyep="text" id="lengthtoti2" name="pricefn22" value="">
<br><br><br>
</form>
////////////////////////THIRD FORM/////////////////////////////
<form id="formaddi3" class="formadd3">
<br>
<label for="standardi3">Standard</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="packn3" id ="standardi3" class="quip3 standard3 qr3" value="1050" checked><br><br>

<label for="equippedi3">Equipped</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="packn3" id ="equippedi3" class="quip3 equipped3 qr3" value="0" ><br><br>

<label for="gpsi3">GPS</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="gpsn3" id ="gpsi3" value="20" class ="gps3 qr3"><br><br>

<label for="boosteri3">booster</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="boostern3" id ="boosteri3" value="20" class ="booster3 qr3"><br><br>

<label for="onetenti3">One tent</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="tentn3" id ="onetenti3" class="stent3 onetent3 qr3" value="1350" disabled><br><br>

<label for="twotenti3">Two tents :</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="tentn3" id ="twotenti3" class="stent3 twotent3 qr3" value="1450" disabled><br><br>
Daily :<span id="dailytotali3"> </span><br><br>
Total :<span id="lengthtotali3"> </span><br><br>

<br><input tyep="text" id="dailytoti3" name="pricefn13" value="">
<br><input tyep="text" id="lengthtoti3" name="pricefn23" value="">
<form>
```

```
function Calc() {
    //get the values of the selected options
      var counter = $("#countrows").val();
      let totals = [];
            for (i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
      totals[i] = 0;
      $.each($('.qr' + i + ':checked'), function() {
        totals[i] += parseInt($(this).val());
      });
      console.log(totals[i]);
    $('#dailytotali' + i).text('R' + totals[i] + '/day');
    $('#lengthtotali' + i).text('R' + totals[i] * parseFloat($("#nosday").val()) + '/day');
    $('#dailytoti' + i).val(totals[i]);
    $('#lengthtoti' + i).val(totals[i] * parseFloat($("#nosday").val()));

      }

}       
Calc();

$("[class*=qr]").on("change", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
Calc();

});

function Equip() 
    {
    var counter1 = $("#countrows").val();
        for (i = 1; i <= counter1; i++) {
$('input.onetent'+ i).eq(i).prop("disabled", false);
$('input.twotent'+ i).eq(i).prop("disabled", false);
$('input.onetent'+ i).eq(i).prop("checked", true);
$('input.standard'+ i).eq(i).prop("checked", false);
        }
    }
    function Standard() 
    {
    var counter2 = $("#countrows").val();
        for (i = 1; i <= counter2; i++) {
    $('#formaddi'+ i).children('input.onetent'+ i).eq(i).prop("checked", false);
    $('#formaddi'+ i).children('input.twotent'+ i).eq(i).prop("checked", false);
        $('#formaddi'+ i).children('input.onetent'+ i).eq(i).prop("disabled", true);
        $('#formaddi'+ i).children('input.twotent'+ i).eq(i).prop("disabled", true);
    $('#formaddi'+ i).children('input.equipped'+ i).eq(i).prop("checked", false);
        }
    }
    function twoTent()
    {
    var counter3 = $("#countrows").val();
    for (i = 1; i <= counter3; i++) {
        $('#formaddi'+ i).children('input.onetent'+ i).eq(i).prop("checked", false);
    }
    }
    function oneTent()
    {
    var counter4 = $("#countrows").val();
    for (i = 1; i <= counter4; i++) {
        $('#formaddi'+ i).children('input.twotent'+ i).eq(i).prop("checked", false);
    }
    }
$("[id^=standardi]").click(function() {
Standard();
});
$("[id^=equippedi]").click(function() {
Equip();
});
$("[id^=onetenti]").click(function() {
oneTent();
}); 
$("[id^=twotenti]").click(function() {
twoTent();
```

Comment: This is a fairly complex logic here. Could you give an example of what you click, what happens and what you would want to happen?

Comment: @GaloisGirl Alright assuming you've looked at the Fiddle. **FIRST FORM** - click `input field where name is packn1`  and `id = "equippedi1". **First Action** - **uncheck** `id="standardi1"` **Second Action** - **disable false for all inputs with class="stent1"** **Third Action** - **check** `input` where `id="onetenti1"` The calculation is already done when it changes so that doesnt matter, that part of it works fine. **Next Function** **Click**->`id=''standardi1"`->**uncheck if checked** `id="equippedi1" - > **Disable true** -> `class="stent1"` -> **uncheck if checked** ->

Comment: `either class="stent1"`

Comment: Basically each form must only be able to uncheck or disable in itself where `i` iterates until it reaches `var counter = $("#countrows").val();`

Comment: What about using `$counter.each(function() {`?

Comment: would there be a way to use `$(this)` to obtain the number at the end of the class or id to use to only uncheck related elements?

Comment: @GaloisGirl Best solution i can find below.

Answer (score 0):

Link for answer and explanation: [Select characters after index in order to select another element with the same characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849483/select-characters-after-index-in-order-to-select-another-element-with-the-same-c)

Code Below :

```js
function Calc() {
  //get the values of the selected options
  var counter = $("#countrows").val();
  let totals = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
    totals[i] = 0;
    $.each($('.qr' + i + ':checked'), function() {
      totals[i] += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(totals[i]);
    $('#dailytotali' + i).text('R' + totals[i] + '/day');
    $('#lengthtotali' + i).text('R' + totals[i] * parseFloat($("#nosday").val()) + '/day');
    $('#dailytoti' + i).val(totals[i]);
    $('#lengthtoti' + i).val(totals[i] * parseFloat($("#nosday").val()));

  }

}
Calc();

$("[class*=qr]").on("change", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  Calc();

});

function Equip(thisid) {
  var that = $(thisid).attr('id');
  var thisstr1 = String(that);
  var lastChar = thisstr1.substr(thisstr1.lastIndexOf('i') + 1);
  console.log(that);
  console.log(thisstr1);
  console.log(lastChar);
  $('input.onetentc' + lastChar).prop("disabled", false);
  $('input.twotentc' + lastChar).prop("disabled", false);
  $('input.onetentc' + lastChar).prop("checked", true);
  $('input.standardc' + lastChar).prop("checked", false);
}

function Standard(thisid) {
  var that1 = $(thisid).attr('id');
  var thisstr = String(that1);
  var lastChar1 = thisstr.substr(thisstr.indexOf('i') + 1)
  console.log(that1);
  console.log(thisstr);
  console.log(lastChar1);
  $('input.onetentc' + lastChar1).prop("checked", false);
  $('input.twotentc' + lastChar1).prop("checked", false);
  $('input.onetentc' + lastChar1).prop("disabled", true);
  $('input.twotentc' + lastChar1).prop("disabled", true);
}
$("[id*=standardi]").click(function() {
  Standard($(this));
});
$("[id*=equippedi]").click(function() {
  Equip($(this));
});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;
  -ms-appearance: checkbox;
  /* not currently supported */
  -o-appearance: checkbox;
  /* not currently supported */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="5" id="nosday"><br><br>
<input type="hidden" value="3" id="countrows"><br> ////////////////////////FIRST FORM/////////////////////////////
<br>
<form id="formaddi1" class="formadd1">

  <label for="standardi1">Standard</label>
  <input type="radio" name="packn1" id="standardi1" class="pack1 standardc1 qr1" value="1050" checked><br><br>

  <label for="equippedi1">Equipped</label>
  <input type="radio" name="packn1" id="equippedi1" class="pack1 equippedc1 qr1" value="0"><br><br>

  <label for="gpsi1">GPS</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="gpsn1" id="gpsi1" value="20" class="gpsc1 qr1"><br><br>

  <label for="boosteri1">booster</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="boostern1" id="boosteri1" value="20" class=" boosterc1 qr1"><br><br>

  <label for="onetenti1">One tent</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tentn1" id="onetenti1" class="stent1 onetentc1 qr1" value="1350" disabled><br><br>

  <label for="twotenti1">Two tents :</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tentn1" id="twotenti1" class="stent1 twotentc1 qr1" value="1450" disabled><br><br> Daily :<span id="dailytotali1"> </span><br><br> Total :<span id="lengthtotali1"> </span>
  <br><br>
  <br><input tyep="text" id="dailytoti1" name="pricefn11" value="">
  <br><input tyep="text" id="lengthtoti1" name="pricefn21" value="">
  <br><br><br>
</form>
////////////////////////SECOND FORM/////////////////////////////
<BR>
<form id="formaddi2" class="formadd2">
  <label for="standardi2">Standard</label>
  <input type="radio" name="packn2" id="standardi2" class="quip2 standardc2 qr2" value="125" checked><br><br>

  <label for="equippedi2">Equipped</label>
  <input type="radio" name="packn2" id="equippedi2" class="quip2 equippedc2 qr2" value="0"><br><br>

  <label for="gpsi2">GPS</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="gpsn2" id="gpsi2" value="20" class="gpsc2 qr2"><br><br>

  <label for="boosteri2">booster</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="boostern2" id="boosteri2" value="20" class="boosterc2 qr2"><br><br>

  <label for="onetenti2">One tent</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tentn2" id="onetenti2" class="stent2 onetentc2 qr2" value="1350" disabled><br><br>

  <label for="twotenti2">Two tents :</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tentn2" id="twotenti2" class="stent2 twotentc2 qr2" value="1450" disabled><br><br> Daily :<span id="dailytotali2"> </span><br><br> Total :<span id="lengthtotali2"> </span><br><br>

  <br><input tyep="text" id="dailytoti2" name="pricefn12" value="">
  <br><input tyep="text" id="lengthtoti2" name="pricefn22" value="">
  <br><br><br>
</form>
////////////////////////THIRD FORM/////////////////////////////
<form id="formaddi3" class="formadd3">
  <br>
  <label for="standardi3">Standard</label>
  <input type="radio" name="packn3" id="standardi3" class="quip3 standardc3 qr3" value="1050" checked><br><br>

  <label for="equippedi3">Equipped</label>
  <input type="radio" name="packn3" id="equippedi3" class="quip3 equippedc3 qr3" value="0"><br><br>

  <label for="gpsi3">GPS</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="gpsn3" id="gpsi3" value="20" class="gpsc3 qr3"><br><br>

  <label for="boosteri3">booster</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="boostern3" id="boosteri3" value="20" class="boosterc3 qr3"><br><br>

  <label for="onetenti3">One tent</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tentn3" id="onetenti3" class="stent3 onetentc3 qr3" value="1350" disabled><br><br>

  <label for="twotenti3">Two tents :</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tentn3" id="twotenti3" class="stent3 twotentc3 qr3" value="1450" disabled><br><br> Daily :<span id="dailytotali3"> </span><br><br> Total :<span id="lengthtotali3"> </span><br><br>

  <br><input tyep="text" id="dailytoti3" name="pricefn13" value="">
  <br><input tyep="text" id="lengthtoti3" name="pricefn23" value="">
</form>
```

After a few more hours of research I came up with a solution to my problem by pulling info from over 20 different stack overflow questions in order to come up with an easy solution. If any of my information is incorrect I apologize, please feel free to comment on what I've gotten wrong. If you have any other suggestions, I welcome them.

Passed `$(this);` from `click` function to `function Standard ()` and `function Equip()`. created var for `$(this)` to use in variable assignment of `lastChar` which provides the character after an `Index`. `String()` is used to convert the object `$(this)` to a string and assigned to a new variable `thisstr`. `lastChar` variable assigned to the character after an index through the use of `lastIndexOf` which finds the last index matching index in a string and provides any characters after it.

`var lastChar = thisstr1.substr(thisstr1.lastIndexOf('i') + 1);`

Is used to find characters after `('i')` where i is the last character in the string.

`var thisstr = String(that);`
Is the line that converts `var that = $(this).attr('id');` from an object to a string as `$(this) is used to reference a DOM element and not a specific string in the following example :

```
$("#id").click(functon()
{
  var vas = $(this).val();
  var do = (".class").text(vas);
});
```

`$(this)` is the DOM element, i.e. an input, div, span etc in it's entirety.
val() is the definition to find the value of that element.
This is handy in using short hand coding and making easy reference to the element in question and can be used in loops, functions, from one function to the next. etc.

To avoid checking or unchecking; checkboxes I decided to go for radio buttons disguised as checkboxes, only because I required them for aesthetics. `console.log();` is not really required for me but I left it in there to check all is working well.